# Does Webkit not work with shopify liquid?

Tags: css, css-animations, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add a gradient animation to my website background, I can get the gradient in there but the animation part is not working? This is through a pre built shopify store. does webkit not work with shopify's liquid?[Here is the image of the code I inserted, just pure CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCMjl.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding a copy of your keyframes that's just `@keyframes Gradient`? You don't need the -webkit prefix for that on Chrome (anymore) -- maybe it's been deprecated and removed in a recent release?

Comment: Is it that your keyframes are nested inside the `body,html{` block and they need to be outside of all wrapping `{}`s?

Comment: Wow! that was it, so simple thank you so much Dave!

Comment: Glad I was able to have a random insight that helped!  Which of those comments solved the issue? I'll copy the one that worked to an answer so that you can mark this question as solved :)

Comment: It needed to be outside of the body,html{}

Answer (score 0):

Shopify Liquid has nothing to do with Webkit. Shopify renders HTML, CSS and JS to browsers the same as any other hosted service, for example Wordpress.

If you are having CSS issues, you'll have to track those down like everyone else, using your typical browser inspector tools, and debug from there.

Comment: weird because it runs perfectly fine in any other program I use

Comment: You just got lucky and or have not really tested much across a broad spectrum. Sometimes we fail to see the forest for the trees. All you need to know is your problem is not Shopify, but is standard HTML/CSS/JS stuff you can work out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that your keyframes are nested inside the `body,html{` block and they need to be outside of all wrapping `{}`s?

It looks like the file that you're working in is a `scss` file, which allows you to nest CSS definitions, so it may be that your keyframes are just showing up in an invalid place in the final CSS.